# When I clicked on submit button nothing showed up in my database

Tags: python, html, django, forms

I have a register form but when I click on submit button nothing show up in my database and when I created superuser that user was saved to database but if I register with the form it does nothing.

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms


class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
            'password1', 'password2'
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegisterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['first_name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'First Name', 'id': 'first-name'})
        self.fields['last_name'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Last Name', 'id': 'last-name'})
        self.fields['email'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Email Address', 'id': 'email-address'})
        self.fields['password1'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'New Password', 'id': 'password1'})
        self.fields['password2'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Re-enter New Password', 'id': 'password2'})
```

views.py

```
# login and register function
def loginAndRegister(request):
    # register form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
            registerForm.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Your account has created successfully! you can log in now')
            return redirect('login')
    else:
        registerForm = RegisterForm()

    context = {'registerForm': registerForm}
    return render(request, 'account/loginAndRegisterPage.html', context)
```

html view

```
<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}
  
  <li>{{ registerForm.first_name }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.last_name }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.email }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.password1 }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.password2 }}</li>

  <li><input type="submit" value="Create Account"></li>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not working because I used duplicate name in first name and last name and also because I used the customize form it didn't show me any error and that's why I don't what's wrong with form.

Answer (score 0):

#### Below Your `csrf_token` you need to have this tag `{{registerForm.as_p}}`

```
<form method='POST'>
  {% csrf_token %}

  {{  registerForm.as_p  }}  # `as_p` to get nicely formatted and clean form

  <li>{{ registerForm.first_name }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.last_name }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.email }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.password1 }}</li>
  <li>{{ registerForm.password2 }}</li>

  <input type="submit" value="Create Account">
</form>
```

**Happy Coding!, *Please-Please Let Me Know For Any Issues With This I'am For you just comment down below how was the solution and let me know if this solution worked out!***

Comment: I used `{{ registerForm.first_name }}` because I want to customize the form with css

Comment: I mean `{{ registerForm.as_p }}` will give me a default style of django but I don't want my form to have that look so in `forms.py` I gave widget attribute to my fields to customize the form with css and bootstrap. But the problem is when I clicked submit button it saved nothing into my database.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try Doing This To Your `views.py`

```
# login and register function
def loginAndRegister(request):
    # register form
    if request.method == 'POST':
        registerForm = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if registerForm.is_valid():
           new_user = registerForm.save()  # Maybe You Are Saving The Entire Form?
           new_user.save()
           messages.success(request, 'Your account has created successfully! you can log in now')
           return redirect('login')
    else:
        registerForm = RegisterForm()

    context = {'registerForm': registerForm}
    return render(request, 'account/loginAndRegisterPage.html', context)
```

Comment: still got the same problem